# error: Merge failed: Something went wrong during merge: 3:invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII. Please try again. on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, git-rebase, conventional-commits, github-flow

Using GitLab

Received the following error message.

```
Merge failed: Something went wrong during merge: 3:invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII. Please try again.
```

[image]

solution to follow.

Answer (score 0):

We have a regex pattern on the Commit Messages to enforce a part of the conventional commits that were added after the initial few commits made on the project.  Example of regex answered [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899999/regexp-to-match-conventional-commit-syntax/62293234#62293234)

### Merge into Master failed

two commits don't follow [conventional commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899999/regexp-to-match-conventional-commit-syntax/62293234#62293234).

```
 * 119a135 - (HEAD -> master) docs(devops): a primer (6 minutes ago) <Casey Burnett>
 * beb03e6 - Add contribution guide (6 minutes ago) <Guy>  ### Note to Stackoverflow: this is missing type
 * f314c3e - initial commit (6 minutes ago) <Guy>  ### Note to Stackoverflow: git boilerplate is case sensitive to `Initial commit`
 * 4d04254 - Initial commit (8 weeks ago) <Mr. Robot>
```

### A Solution

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

follow prompts of [interactive git-rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) and update two commits to "reword".  An additional resource for [git-base interactive](https://linuxize.com/post/change-git-commit-message/)

For us, because we follow GitHub flow, I merged the updated master into my working branch and pushed it up for review.

```
git checkout docs/conventional-commit-examples
git merge master
git push origin docs/conventional-commit-examples
```